# Azure Web Jobs architecture

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have some code that needs to run as a result of a call to a service bus.  This particular code is CPU intensive and it is possible that 100s of these will need to run at the same time.  Does Azure Web Jobs use computing resources from one machine, or does it use any available computing resources from several machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Jobs uses your web app resources, why don't you try the **[Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-portal/)** which can be scaled and their pricing is almost zero. They are in Technical preview i have tried using it, Azure functions is very cheap. If your service bus call can be out of process service meaning it does not need a instance results from your application you can try azure functions. Azure functions are mostly used for maintenance and night time running jobs. I have used it to minify my images to thumbnail. It worked perfectly fine

Comment: Yeah, if only Azure Functions existed when I wrote that post, I would have used it.  :)

Comment: If you look at the comment I wrote on Steeples post, it was basically describing Azure Functions.  I think someone at Azure or AWS read that and created Azure Functions and AWS Lambda.  I take full credit.

Comment: You may be right, dascalos. You are a real visionary !! :)

Comment: I kind of disagree with the **"their pricing is almost zero"** part of the statement. It is easy to control your costs by selecting the right pricing model adapted for your needs, like most Azure services. And yes, it is affordable in comparison.

Comment: 1 million execution free per month and if u have proper micro-services then u can get away fr free. Each az function gives 1 million free execution

Answer (score 1):

Azure Webjobs is designed to run on as many servers as you've scaled up the website to run on. By default it will run up to 16 tasks from a queue concurrently but this is configurable as shown [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/06/announcing-the-0-5-0-beta-preview-of-microsoft-azure-webjobs-sdk/).

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.Queues.BatchSize= 1;
        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: The BatchSize configuration does not apply for ServiceBus queues. We are tracking this and we are probably going to support parallel execution for ServiceBus but for now ServiceBus triggered functions run sequential.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I do love the WebJobs.  They work great for certain use cases.  I actually use them for nightly data imports.  What I would love is another service that uses a similar sdk to the webjobs but as work comes in it spawns processes out in the pool of available computing resources and does the work.  I don't want to have to worry if I have enough cpus spawned up.  Similar to the worker roles but more lightweight and more elasticy.  Can I get an Amen?  Am I missing something that exists?

Comment: @dascalos I think that's a great idea. I hope you don't mind but I've added it as a feedback request on the Azure Uservoice: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/6440654-allow-webjobs-to-scale-dynamically-and-independent

Answer (score 0):

A web job deployed as part of an Azure WebSite will share the resources with the web application. You have the option to scale the website up to 10 (I think?) instances if you need parallelism.

As I mentioned in the comment to Matthew's post, if you use the Azure WebJobs SDK to have functions triggered by ServiceBus queue messages, we don't parallelize as part of the same host. This means that messages will be processed sequentially as long as you have a single host.